# Quickblox fill full video with QBRTCRemoteVideoView

Tags: ios, video, quickblox

I use Quickblox SDK to capture camera on my phone.
I use QBRTCRemoteVideoView to get video track like sample code of Quickblox SDK.
I want to make video full frame but it can't. I change ViewMode of QBRTCRemoteVideoView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill like their suggest but it can't fill full frame.
I config QBRTCVideoFormat but it can't work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following category(as for now it is an internal API) :

```
@interface QBRTCRemoteVideoView (VideoGravity)

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) QBRTCSampleBufferRenderer *renderer;

@end
```

Then you can use property

```
QBRTCRemoteVideoView *videoView = your_video_view;
QBRTCSampleBufferView *view = (QBRTCSampleBufferView *)videoView.renderer.rendererView;
 view.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

We will open this API in the next version of QuickbloxWebRTC iOS SDK.

Thanks!